# How to close all threads and end connection

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

I am trying to implement the code as written here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/simple-chat-room-using-python/

I can get it to run properly but cannot find a way to close the connection. The code simply runs until I enter a keyboard interrupt. I'l like to implement a keyword that will shut down the client and server and free the port.

I've implemented the client code to exit if the message is "quit" but the same technique isn't working in the server code. I keep getting caught on the "conn, addr = server.accept()" line and it returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newServer.py", line 66, in <module>
    conn, addr = server.accept()
  File "/Users/######/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 212, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
ConnectionAbortedError: [Errno 53] Software caused connection abort
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Adding code

server.py:

```
import socket
import select
from _thread import *
import threading
import sys


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
"""
the first argument AF_INET is the address domain of the socket. This is used when we have an Internet Domain
with any two hosts
The second argument is the type of socket. SOCK_STREAM means that data or characters are read in a continuous flow
"""
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

IP_address = "127.0.0.1"
Port = 12230

server.bind((IP_address, Port)) 
#binds the server to an entered IP address and at the specified port number. The client must be aware of these parameters
server.listen(100)
#listens for 100 active connections. This number can be increased as per convenience
list_of_clients=[]

def clientthread(conn, addr):
    conn.send("Welcome to this chatroom!".encode())
    #sends a message to the client whose user object is conn
    while True:
            try:     
                message = conn.recv(2048).decode()
                if message:
                    print ("<" + addr[0] + "> " + message)
                    message_to_send = "<" + addr[0] + "> " + message
                    broadcast(message_to_send,conn)
                    #prints the message and address of the user who just sent the message on the server terminal
                else:
                    remove(conn)
            except:
                continue

def broadcast(message,connection):
    for clients in list_of_clients:
        if clients!=connection:
            try:
                clients.send(message.encode())
            except:
                clients.close()
                remove(clients)

def remove(connection):
    if connection in list_of_clients:
        list_of_clients.remove(connection)

while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    """
    Accepts a connection request and stores two parameters, conn which is a socket object for that user, and addr which contains
    the IP address of the client that just connected
    """
    list_of_clients.append(conn)
    print (addr[0] + " connected")
    #maintains a list of clients for ease of broadcasting a message to all available people in the chatroom
    #Prints the address of the person who just connected
    start_new_thread(clientthread,(conn,addr))
    #creates and individual thread for every user that connects

conn.close()
server.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket 
import select 
import sys 

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

IP_address = "127.0.0.1"
Port = 12230

server.connect((IP_address, Port)) 

while True: 

    # maintains a list of possible input streams 
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server] 

    """ There are two possible input situations. Either the 
    user wants to give  manual input to send to other people, 
    or the server is sending a message  to be printed on the 
    screen. Select returns from sockets_list, the stream that 
    is reader for input. So for example, if the server wants 
    to send a message, then the if condition will hold true 
    below.If the user wants to send a message, the else 
    condition will evaluate as true"""
    read_sockets,write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[]) 

    for socks in read_sockets: 
        if socks == server: 
            message = socks.recv(2048).decode()
            print (message)
        else: 
            message = input("Message: ")
            server.send(message.encode()) 
            print("<You>") 
            print(message) 
server.close()
```

Comment: And you are running it in python 2.X?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned. I'm running in python3 but changed the existing code to work on python 3 (print statements, thread library)

Comment: Hmm well maybe you could toss the scripts on here in case something was improperly converted to 3.X, plus it would give us the relevant code surrounding `conn, addr = server.accept()`

Comment: @Reedinationer just did!

Comment: Hmmm the line `read_sockets, write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list, [], [])` generates the error `OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket` for me but the server still prints `127.0.0.1 connected`.

Comment: It isn't showing that error for me. I'm running on a mac and it seems like that's a windows error, maybe that's it?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like it from the `OSError: [WinError 10038]` I'll leave it to a Mac user to help you out :)